# Time data from API convert to Date time python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

i have this problem with milliseconds or microseconds data from api im not totally sure. I am trying to convert this to a readable date time. below is an example. The web app has a dashboard which you i can check the date time. but i do not know exactly how to convert it to a readable date time.

**Example 1:**

FROM API
"start":1542243678,

FROM Dashboard
11/15/2018 9:01 am

**Example 2:**

FROM API
"end":1542330078,

FROM Dashboard
11/16/2018 9:01 am

When i try to convert to python date time it gives me wrong info.

```
import datetime
import time

milliseconds = 1542243678

date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(milliseconds/1000.0)

date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(date)
```

Output:
1970-01-19 04:24:03

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1542243678).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` -> `'2018-11-14 17:01:18'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I don't understand your question correctly, but is this what you want?

```
import datetime
import time

milliseconds = 1542243678

date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(milliseconds)

date = date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

print(date)
```

Output: 11/14/2018 05:01 PM

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to divide by 1000 before passing to datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp.
Try datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1542243678). It should work.